# How to add security to spring based rest api's and static content

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a web application + a set of rest APIs created with spring. It is essentially some html pages sending ajax requests to the rest server.  The structure looks somewhat like this:

myWebapp -> src/main/webapp/public (public pages)
myWebapp -> src/main/webapp/resources (non - public pages, available only after login)

I need to secure some of the static content (non-public above) and the rest APIs (Preferably with LDAP, but that's not important). How do i configure the filters and/or spring security intercepts so that:

1. Same credentials work for both static content and rest calls.
2. User can login via a login page, and for further rest calls uses some token or something returned from server.

I have checked spring security schemes for rest API's and also found some resources on securing static content, but not able to figure out how to fit this together as above.

Comment: what is the URL path for your restful services?

Comment: @AnanthaSharma Rest resources are served at /rest/api/<specific paths>. While the static pages, css, js etc. at usual /public/js/blah.js etc (public) and /resources/user/myhome.html (non public)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to have two sets of resources. One of them is open for public access and available at, say, `/public` context and the other is protected and available at `/protected`.

First, you should create some `Resource Handlers` in your `Web Configuration`:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    // other stuffs

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/public/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/protected/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/");
    }
}
```

This way all the static contents in `/public` directory will be served at `/public/**` endpoint and `/protected/**` endpoint will serve files in the `/resources` directory.

Then you should configure Spring Security in order to protect `/protected/**` endpoint:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // other stuffs

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/protected/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

**Update** For REST endpoints you can either use same the matchers or have finer grain control with `Method Level Security`. In order to enable method level security, add `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` to your `SecurityConfig`. Then you can use `PrePost` annotations on hanlder methods, like following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/greet")
public class GreetingService {
    // it's a public rest endpoint
    @PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
    @RequestMapping("/public")
    public void doGreetToPublicUsers() {...}

    // it's a protected rest endpoint
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    @RequestMapping("/protected")
    public void doGreetToProtectedUsers() {...}

    // it's a role protected rest endpoint
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @RequestMapping("/admin")
    public void justForAdmin() {...}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. This tells me how I can have auth for static resources selectively. But can you also show me how I can have the same auth work for rest services. Basically like a user logs in once through a form or something, and then all rest calls that come in via ajax use the same authentication.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ended up using the xml based version of above with jdbc authentication.